# How efficient is changing window root viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, uiwindow

Im making an app which the user can log in to and log out. I check if a saved user exists (from earlier logins) and if a user is saved I log that user in and then change rootviewcontroller for the window to the viewcontroller that should appear when logged in.

```
// In LoginViewController
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) // Login viewcontrollers as login, facebook login, register is inside its own storyboard called Login
let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as MainViewController

let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!

window.rootViewController = vc
```

But Im just wondering, how efficient is this?

Will it handle the memory properly by just doing this?

Comment: Xcode offers an array of profiling tools. I suggest you use those tools to determine for yourself whether the memory/processor impact is acceptable.

Comment: Im not very used to Instruments and I find it much easier to ask someone who might already know, and also the answerer get reputation :D

Comment: You are trying to optimize something without knowing that it's a problem. If you are experiencing performance issues in your app, your *only* recourse is to use Instruments to find the problem areas. People on Stack Overflow can answer individual questions like the one you have asked, but it does not necessarily address your underlying desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not do anything special. It is similar to presenting/dismissing view controller.

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window.
>   Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the window has an existing view
>   hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are
>   installed.

It will handle memory properly as long as you handle memory properly (no retain cycles between views, view controllers, delegates etc.).

Of course detailed numbers can be found using time, allocations profiling instruments (as [@Ian MacDonald suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813183/how-efficient-is-changing-window-root-viewcontroller#comment45898355_28813183))

Off topic a bit: as for me it is a preferred way to switch between logged-in/logged-out states of the app. I believe this approach leads to simplified screen navigation between logged-in/logged-out state: once you log in you change root vc to your data controller and forget about login stuff.

Comment: Thanks for you answer this was what I was looking for. And yes I think this is a pretty good good solution to change root vc when loged in and then hange to login vc again when logged out and skip login view completely if a saved user exists :)